# Google Sheets - Count Unique Values in Importrange with a condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count the number of unique text values in a column that respect a certain condition in another column. The table is:

| Name | Beta |
| --- | --- |
| Lorem | Y |
| Lorem | Y |
| Ipsum | N |
| Dolorem | Y |

- The formula needs to be in a different google workbook than where the the above table is, so I will need to use the function importrange
- I understand that I cannot use the functions countunique or filter with importrange, so I am trying to use the function query

The expected result should be 2. I also placed the fomulas tried and data in this open google sheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7q\_-spjoKuphxVXtDkbQn17rgbRNG9QaXaZIXKX7Dg/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7q%5C_-spjoKuphxVXtDkbQn17rgbRNG9QaXaZIXKX7Dg/edit?usp=sharing)

*What formula should I use?*

I tried to use both examples below but did not succeed:

1. =UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B5; "Select count (A) where B = 'Y' label count(A)  ''"))
2. =COUNTA(unique(QUERY(A2:B5; "Select (A) where B = 'Y'")))

The second fomula seems to work, but if I test it with no value respecting the condition B="Y" it still reports 1.

**: For the sake of this example and to keep it simple to explain, in the two examples that I tried  I did not use the function importrange but I will actually need to use it in the final solution

Comment: shared sheet does not exists

Answer (score 1):

after `COUNTA` there should always be `IFNA`

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B5; "select A where B = 'Y'"))))
```

also, keep in mind that a blank cell is also a unique cell so sometimes you may add another condition:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B5; "select A where B = 'Y' and A is not null"))))
```